# Returning back to the beginning of a loop using "continue" on Java

Tags: java

```
public void talk() {
    String[] prompts = {"Describe to me in a sentence why this is a cool program.", 
            "Describe to me in a sentence how your day was.", 
            "Describe to me in a sentence what programming means to you.", 
            "Describe to me in a sentence why food is neccessary for humans."};
    iramInLoop = true;
    while(iramInLoop)
    {
        int i = new Random().nextInt(prompts.length);
        System.out.println(prompts[i]);
        String input = Raybot.getInput();

        if(!checkPunc(input) && !checkCaps(input)){
            System.out.println("Check your capitalization and your punctuation!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Great grammar keep it up! Do you want to try again?");  
            if(input.equals("yes")) continue;
            else
            {
                iramInLoop = false;
                Raybot.talkForever();//this exits the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am having extreme trouble trying to restart my loop. So at the end of my code when the loop is done running I put a string which asks if the user wants to try again and if the user says yes I want it to go back to the beginning of the loop and do what the loop does again. However, every time I run it it goes to the end of the loop and doesn't even ask for an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be *breaking* out of the loop if the person guessed right, but then decided not to continue.  In this case, your logic should be something like this:

```
while (true) {
    int i = new Random().nextInt(prompts.length);
    System.out.println(prompts[i]);
    String input = Raybot.getInput();

    if (!checkPunc(input) && !checkCaps(input)) {
        System.out.println("Check your capitalization and your punctuation!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Great grammar keep it up! Do you want to try again?");  
        input = Raybot.getInput();
        if (input.equals("no")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// whatever this does, you intended for it happen after the loop terminates, so do it here
Raybot.talkForever();
```

Comment: That is exiting the loop if the user says no correct? How would I return back to the beginning of the loop if the user says yes?

Comment: @IramShahed If the user _doesn't_ say "no," then loop would automatically continue (forever), returning to the beginning again.

Comment: The just needed to put the Raybot.talkForever(); outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to actually accept any input

maybe

```
System.out.println("Great grammar keep it up! Do you want to try again?");  
input = Raybot.getInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

change `if(input.equals("yes")) continue;`

to `if(Raybot.getInput().equals("yes")) continue;`

Comment: Since u're printing *Do you want to try again?* .. i suppose you might need another input after it?